# SQL Join two tables and check the existence of each value in both tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

We have 3 main tables `Order` , `Pickup` and `Delivery`
Under one `OrderID` there are multiple Items (1 to many)

- Some items in the order might have been picked up without delivery and vice versa.
- Some order with all its items might have been picked up without a single delivery of its items and vice versa.
- Some order all of its items will be picked up and delivered.

So I want to have a list of order ID then the picked up items for the order. if the order id not exists in pickup but exists in delivery that means the pickup is missing and show 'Not picked up'
and vise versa , If the item is in pickup but not in delivery that means delivery is missing and will show 'Not delivered'

From above cases you can see below sample data with the expected result

Order Table

```
OrderID 
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
```

Pickup Table

```
OrderID | PickupItem | Date               OrderID | DeliveryItem | Date
  1    |   1100     | 13-02-2021            1     |   1100       | 14-02-2021
  2    |   2200     | 06-02-2021            2     |   2201       | 05-02-2021
  2    |   2201     | 06-02-2021            3     |   3300       | 03-02-2021
  3    |   3300     | 04-02-2021            3     |   3301       | 03-02-2021
  4    |   4400     | 07-02-2021            5     |   5500       | 05-02-2021
```

Expected Result

```
OrderID | PickupItem       | PickupDate    | DeliveryItem      | DeliveryDate
  1     |   1100           | 13-02-2021    |     1100          |    13-02-2021
  2     |   2200           | 06-02-2021    |     Not Delivered |    Not Delivered
  2     |   2201           | 06-02-2021    |     2201          |    13-02-2021
  3     |   3300           | 04-02-2021    |     3300          |    13-02-2021
  3     |   Not Picked Up  | Not Picked Up |     3301          |    13-02-2021
  4     |   4400           | 07-02-2021    |     Not Delivered |    Not Delivered
  5     |   Not Picked Up  | Not Picked Up |     5500          |    13-02-2021
```

Comment: Isn't this just two left joins? What do you have so far?

Comment: If I did pickup left join delivery that means some of the delivery items which is not picked up won't be included in the result. For example order 5 won't be included

Comment: How about `from [order] left join pickup... left join delivery...`

Comment: I didn't believe it would be that simple I will give it a try. But how to map same items in both pickup and delivery in one line? for example order 2 if we did the left join 2200 will be in the same line/row with 2201

Comment: Do you not have `PickupItem` in the `Order` table also, or perhaps a separate `Pickup` table? If not there is something wrong with your DB design

Comment: @Charlieface Unfortunately not , The design is so poor and I'm here struggling

Comment: You should have a table indicating all items that are part of each order. Without it you can't represent items that are neither picked up or delivered.

Comment: @MatBailie What if I have created view using above tables to have that info. Like having order id and distinct not duplicated items from pickup and delivery tables?

Comment: Nope, that still doesn't cover items that are both Not Picked and Not Delivered at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database design is poor, as you have no reference point for the existence of a `PickupItem`. We need to use a nested `FULL JOIN` to get the results from both tables:

```sql
select o.orderid, p.pickupitem, p.date,
       d.deliveryitem, d.date
from [order] o
left join
     (pickup p
     full join delivery d
        on d.DeliveryItem = p.pickupitem and d.orderid = p.orderid)
on o.orderid = isnull(d.orderid, p.orderid) ;
```

Comment: d (delivery) is not having pickupItem

Comment: Ah sorry fixed that

Comment: You're a legend !! I will test few more cases just to make sure

Answer (score 0):

This is two `left join`s, but it is tricky.  The second left join needs to refer to both tables -- one for the order id and the other for the item:

```
select o.orderid, p.pickupitem, p.date,
       d.deliveryitem, d.date
from orders o left join
     pickups p
     on o.orderid = p.orderid left join
     delivery d
     on o.orderid = d.orderid and p.pickupitem = d.pickupitem;
```

Comment: That only works if there is a pickup, if there is a delivery with no pickup it won't be returned. `full join` might do the trick, but it's a bad database design IMO

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I will try it now and come back with feedback